# React JS - Two links pointed to the same Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have two components one with menu and another one with link. Both are pointed to the same Route.

This is working good in the fist component but into the second component it is working bad. Because it is directing to the route without any problem '/' -> localhost:3000 (th index page)  but it is NOT rendering the component in this code line

```
<Route exact path='/' render={() => <Home />} />
```

Here is the First Component. It is working perfectly. No problem here

```
const MainMenu = (props) => {

  return (
    <div>
    <Router>
      <div className="wrapper2">
        <nav className="main-menu">
          <ul>             
            <li><NavLink className="home-link" 
                activeClassName="active" exact to="/">home</NavLink>
          </li>
          // Another links ommited because they're not part of the problem             
        </nav>
        <div className="page-content">
         <Route exact path='/' render={() => <Home />} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  </div>
  )
}
```

Here is the second component. It is working bad. The route is showing the right url, the index (http://localhost:3000) but it is NOT rendering the 'Home' component. It is continuing showing the last clicked component.

```
const Header = (props) => {
  return (
  <div className="header">
    <div>
      <Router>
      <div>
        <h1>
          //here I have only one link
          <Link className="home-link" exact 
         to='/'>Logo Image<br />             
          </Link>
        </h1>
        <Route exact path='/' render={() => <Home />} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anybody know how solve it? Thanks

Comment: Is there supposed to be two Router components?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean. It is two components pointing to the same route `<Route exact path='/' render={() => <Home />} />` Into the first component there are another routes but it is ommited in this code because they 're not part of the problem

Comment: Each Route is a route within a Router... so a Router can have many Routes. You have 2 different Routers, each with a single Route

Comment: I excluded this line from the second component `<Route exact path='/' render={() => <Home />} />` and it is continuing working bad in the same way that was before

Comment: In the first component I have more than one link (they are ommited in the code). In the second component I have only one link.